# Error in Entity framework query (Missing cast)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
public List<ProjectImpacts> getProjectImpactsByProjeactIDAndImpactName(String prefe , String impcName)
{ 
    String xim =  cecbContext.Impacts.First(i=>i.impt_name.Contains(impcName)).impt_reference;

    IQueryable<ProjectImpacts> query = from c in cecbContext.ProjectImpacts
            join b in cecbContext.Impacts on c.impt_reference equals b.impt_reference             
            where c.proj_reference == prefe && c.impt_reference == xim
            select b.impt_name;

    List<ProjectImpacts> SelectedImpacts = query.ToList(); //query.Select(refe => new ProjectImpacts { impt_reference =   }).ToList();

    return SelectedImpacts;
}
```

I'm getting an error in this query:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your query selects a name at the end:

```
IQueryable<ProjectImpacts> query = from c in cecbContext.ProjectImpacts
    join b in cecbContext.Impacts on c.impt_reference equals b.impt_reference             
    where c.proj_reference == prefe && c.impt_reference == xim
    // select b.impt_name; // <<== Replace this...
    select c;              // <<== with this.
```

The type parameter `T` of the generic `IQueryable<T>` corresponds to the type of the object selected in the query. Since you select a `name` (which is presumably a `string`), you got an `IQueriable<string>`. Once you select `c`, which is `ProjectImpacts`, you'd get `IQueryable<ProjectImpacts>` as your result

Comment: @Gayashan It looks like `ProjectImpacts` is `c`, not `b`; `b` is `Impacts`. Try the changed query and see if it helps.